# Unable to call "done" function in JQuery after POST

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have a Typescript project that also uses JQuery. It uploads a form containing a file using JQuery Form Plugin(http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

After the upload it is supposed to call the "done" function from JQueryDeferred, which it's unable to do. The browser throws an error to it.

I am using the Typescript definition from Definitely Typed: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Here's my code:

```
this.JQuerySelector().ajaxSubmit().done(function (data) {
            var x = data;
            alert("Success : " + x);
        }).fail(function (data) {
                var x = data;
                alert("Error : " + x);
            });
```

The function ajaxSubmit belongs to the "JQuery Form plugin" whose typescript definition is provided here:

```
interface JQuery
{
    ajaxSubmit(arg:{error:any; success:any}): JQuery;
    ajaxSubmit(): JQueryDeferred<JQuery>;
    ajaxForm(): JQuery;
}
```

I've created this partial definition myself and I'm not sure its accurate. The error I see on the browser console is this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'done'
>   DivAndSpan.ts:243 FileUploader.startUpload DivAndSpan.ts:243
>   (anonymous function) Start.ts:50 x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
>   v.handle jquery.js:4766

The file gets posted successfully but the POST response is not received and the "done" function is not called.

Comment: You can only call [done on deffered functions](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/). ajaxSubmit probably does not return this type.

Comment: If you are certain that `ajaxSubmit()` returns a deferred type, then try changing it to `ajaxSubmit().always(function() { /.../ })` and see if it gets called, it might not be resolving

Comment: @Liam Your answer was right. why did you delete it?

Comment: You said *this syntax is not acceptable in Typescript*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajaxSubmit` does not return a deffered type, it uses a success function [details here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api)

It does say

> You can pass any of the standard $.ajax options to ajaxSubmit

But my guess is this was prior to the deffered object change made to the standard `ajax` method so you'll prob have to do it this way:

```
this.JQuerySelector().ajaxSubmit(success: function (data) {
            var x = data;
            alert("Success : " + x);
        },
       error:function (data) {
                var x = data;
                alert("Error : " + x);
            });
```

Comment: This syntax is not acceptable in Typescript. There is an error in the way you've defined success and error functions.

Comment: I don't really know typescript so I presumed that the syntax was in some way different. Glad it helped.